# Android: Picture/icon included in the textbox or spinner using Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to add an icon inside a textbox and a spinner.

The other one is for spinner and the another is for textbox. I don't have any idea how to call this design.

For spinner, upon clicking it the display only is data(text) only.

For textbox, upon clicking it the client name will be remove its like a watermark in HTML.

**Spinner**

[image]

**Textbox**

[image]

Thank you so much.

Comment: Create parent liner layout with icon on left and add spinner or edittext after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the editext you have to use the drawableleft in your edittext tag like this

```
<Edittext 
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/someicon"
/>
```

And for spinner you have to make a separate layout and inflate it with your adapter.

Comment: thank you for your answer..Btw.. What do you mean for this "inflate it with your adapter"?

Comment: I mean that make an adapter for your spinner in which you can put imageview and make a separate layout for your spinner.

Comment: you can refer to this link for more information. androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107